# Python matplotlib cylindrical to mercator projection issue

Tags: python, matplotlib, maps, projection, matplotlib-basemap

I have global satellite gridded precipitation data that I can successfully subset to Alaska in cylindrical coordinates.  The codelet is as follows (sorry for not wrapping the lines):

```
    mapproj = Basemap(projection = 'cyl', resolution = 'l', llcrnrlat=50.0, llcrnrlon=185.0, urcrnrlat=80.0, urcrnrlon=230.0)

    myplot = plt.imshow(datamasked.T, interpolation = 'nearest', cmap = my_cmap, norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin = 0.0, vmax = 10.0, clip = False), extent = (0.0, 360.0, -90.0, 90.0))
```

This code produces the following image: [image]

To get mercator, I only change the relevant lines of code to

```
mapproj = Basemap(projection = 'merc', resolution = 'l', llcrnrlat=50.0, llcrnrlon=185.0, urcrnrlat=80.0, urcrnrlon=230.0,lat_0=65.0,lon_0=207.5)

x0, y0 = mapproj(185.0,50.0)
x1, y1 = mapproj(230.0,80.0)

myplot = mapproj.imshow(datamasked.T, interpolation = 'nearest', cmap = my_cmap, \
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin = 0.0, vmax = 10.0, clip = False), \
extent = (x0, x1, y0, y1))
```

The resulting image from this code is

[image]

This shows the entire data set squeezed to Alaska, not the intended subset as in the cylindrical projection.  The basemap in the cylindrical projection seems to be enough to specify the subset of data.   Not sure how to specify the subset in mercator.  Sorry for the long-winded post but I wanted to be thorough.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you reproduce this with publicly available data? (Always a good practice, and makes it a lot easier to kibitz.)